# Obtaining app private key for APNS .p12?

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to renew my clients APNS certificates to continue sending push notifications using Amazon AWS and I am following this guide http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html

I am having trouble with step 3. I imported the .cer file into Keychain Access, but as you can see in the screenshot there is no drop down/private key associated with the certificate. Does anyone have any experience with this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IesNF.png

Answer (score 0):

I created a new iOS push certificate and found my private key in the login keychain under "Keys". It's easy to miss, but it's mentioned when uploading the Certificate Signing Request to Apple.

The Apple documentation:
"With the creation of your CSR, Keychain Access simultaneously generated a public and private key pair. Your private key is stored on your Mac in the login Keychain by default and can be viewed in the Keychain Access application under the "Keys" category. Your requested certificate will be the public half of your key pair."